# MKMapView not centering on location iOS8

Tags: mkmapview, ios8, mkcoordinateregion

I have my app on two devices, one on an iOS7 enabled device and another on an iOS8 enabled device. My MKMapView is not center on the users location on the iOS8 device but is on the iOS7.

Here is my code, I have requested the use of the users location on another screen.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

[LocationManager sharedInstance];
CLLocation * location = [[LocationManager sharedInstance] getCurrentLocation];
NSLog(@"Location %f %f",location.coordinate.latitude,location.coordinate.longitude);
MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
mapRegion.center = location.coordinate;
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01;
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01;
 NSLog(@"Map Region Lat %f",mapRegion.center.latitude);
NSLog(@"Map Region Long %f ",mapRegion.center.longitude);

self.getDirectionsMap.delegate = self;
[self.getDirectionsMap setRegion:mapRegion animated: NO];
self.getDirectionsMap.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.getDirectionsMap.showsPointsOfInterest=YES;




}
```

My Location Manager object .m

```
+ (LocationManager *)sharedInstance {
if (nil == kLocationManager) {

    kLocationManager = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
}

return kLocationManager;
}

-(CLLocation *)getCurrentLocation{
CLLocation *loc = [_locationManager location];

return loc;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    /* setup location manager */
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [_locationManager setDelegate:self];

    //iOS8 check
    if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

        [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [_locationManager setDistanceFilter:DISTANCE_FILTER];


    return self;
 }
```

My map successful shows the users position but map is not centered. My location also gets logged correctly with the correct coordinates, and this also matches the logged Map region lat and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You viewDidLoad method has not checked that there is actually a location to use yet. If you used a CLLocationManager you could set it going and then it would call the delegate's methods when it has an actual location. I suspect that the iOS device is taking longer to get a GPS reading and it is giving you `nil` in viewDidLoad.

Comment: You are correct in saying that there is a delay. Moving the code to view Will Appear works.

Comment: Even `viewWillAppear` is not the right way. You must check that there really is a location, other devices may take much longer to get a location fix than they take to make your view appear. The CLLocationManager and its delegate methods are far more reliable.

Comment: I see! Reloading the map view once a location is received? Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. There is a protocol called CLLocationManagerDelegate. If your view controller conforms to that and you create a CLLocationManger and set its delegate to be the viewController. The VC's functions will be called when the user's location is found. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/